# Give some features to the "Late Answers" page

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

I was going through the "Late Answers" page in the 10K moderator tools (**not the review queue**) and noticed something... annoying.

Anytime I wanted to *act* on a post, like upvoting it because it was awesome (surprisingly, comfortingly many!) or flagging it because it was crap, I had to actually open a new tab for that post and perform the action there.

It would be *much* nicer if there were some options to act on the post *from that page*. It already renders the entire post, so I can't imagine adding these features would cause too much trouble.

Specifically, I could see:

- Voting, especially up
- Flagging
- An "Edit" link

We already trust reviewers to make these judgement calls without necessarily seeing the related question, it follows that users using the moderation tools should be able to as well.

Comment: You're... kinda describing the Last Answers review queue. Which, incidentally, *does* show the question along with the answer.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I'm asking for similar features to be available on the late answers page of the moderator tools.