# The 10k tools could do with some love

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

Related posts:

[Filter 10k tools by a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267174/filter-10k-tools-by-a-tag)

[Give some features to the “Late Answers” page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286395/give-some-features-to-the-late-answers-page)

Looking at the 10k tools used for reviewing, users are presented with this monstrosity:

[image]

Could this page and its implementation not be changed to act like the standard review queues, with tag filters and navigation to aid quicker reviewing?

[image]

When using the tools for close and reopen votes, I tend to open the links in a new tab and then go through them and close the tabs when I'm done. Not sure if there is an easier way?

Surely it would help the reviewers and the queue sizes if these tools were made easier to use. I understand that each of the tools have different review options presented, but the close votes at least could behave like the standard queues, seeing as it's the largest of the queues.

I know it's low hanging fruit and only useful to a small percentage of users, but these are the users that would arguably use the tools more if they were easier to use.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment here (could use some UX love), but no way should this become just another _work queue_. Having a simple list of recent moderation that I can browse in my own way is valuable.

Comment: @JoshCaswell my view is that I'd probably review more and have a bigger impact on the queues if I was able to filter the posts to posts that I am familiar with and have a simple navigation to go to the next post.

Comment: I agree that filtering would be great, just as long as the overview is still available.

Comment: I don't see this getting love very soon, but yes, we agree. The problem here is the code behind it is a mess...it's a rewrite to do this properly and it's more of a project than we have time for at the moment because of that. We're addressing mod tools in a few ways coming up...hopefully we can do that with 10k in mind as well and piggyback quite a bit.

Comment: @NickCraver thanks for the response. Should I assume status-deferred/declined then?

Comment: @NickCraver SO has messy code behind the scenes??? ***NNNNOoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo***

Comment: @YvetteColomb They named it Stack Overflow for a reason and I think it-...  `Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)`

Comment: I have no idea how the 10K tools work. The only useful thing I noticed happening at 10K was that I could see deleted content.

Comment: What is that page? I've had 10k rep for a long time - never seen that before. Where is it?

Comment: Whoa. Ok, you click the "Review queues" button. Then you click the nearly invisible word "Tools" in the top left. Takes you here: https://stackoverflow.com/tools

Comment: it was a time when 10k tool make us feel responsible now its just crap. afait so doesn't believe in 10k+ user anymore

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ That was supposed to be a secret. Now everyone with 10k rep will be doing moderation :(

Comment: 10k tools is one of the reasons because your todays nice question or answer turns to a good question / answer because it becomes more visible to power-users in "questions/answers with extreme votes".

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any problems with the 10k tools.