# Screenshot overlaps information on the right

Tags: bug, design, internet-explorer

Whilst viewing this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345134/the-10k-tools-could-do-with-some-love?noredirect=1#comment454776_345134), I found that the screenshots provided overlapped the information on the right making it difficult to read.

See screenshot illustrating what I mean:

[image]

I'm using IE Version 11.0.9600.18537.

Screenshot of resolution:

[image]

Issue is linked with wrapping image in `<kbd></kbd>` tags.

Comment: Are you viewing the site at full width? What resolution are you on?

Comment: @Oded, screenshot added for resolution and by _full width_ do you mean IE is maximised on my screen? If so, yes.

Comment: also, do the images in your post overlap the siderbar? possibly not as they appear to be narrower than mine.

Comment: @Tanner, yes zoom is 100% and no user scripts. And no not for me but my images don't quite reach if you know what I mean. I'm not sure if they would overlap should I post a wide screenshot. I can certainly try to see

Comment: I wrapped the image in `<kbd></kbd>` tags, might have an impact on how the images render. In fact let me edit the tags off one of my images to see if you have the issue when they are removed.

Comment: @Bugs can you check if the first image on my post looks any different now, I've removed the tags on that image.

Comment: @Tanner yes that's sorted it.

Comment: @Bugs probably worth adding that information to the case, namely that <kbd> wrapped images cause this issue. It's probably  my fault for using the tags incorrectly.

Comment: Test case at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/292051#292051, using a `<kbd>` tag causes the image to be displayed at full size in IE, instead of being resized to fit the width of a post.

Comment: Thanks @Stijn, yes this looks to be a duplicate. Happy to mark as such.

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, added info.